# v-on:change does not work for vue-multiselect

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-events

I am using vue-multiselect component in my vue.js project, I am using v-on directive to execute a function on the change event ,

```
<multiselect v-model="selected" :options="projects" :searchable="false" :custom-label="customLabel" track-by="name" v-on:change="executeLoader">
<template slot="customLabel" slot-scope="{ customLabel }"><strong>{{ option.name }}</strong></template>   
</multiselect>
```

I have example full code here: https://codesandbox.io/s/yjjon0vzxj

the `v-on:change` was working with `<select>` component but it stopped workigng with vue-multiselect ! I tried with `v-on:click="executeLoader"` but that too didnt worked either..

Comment: What would you like to achieve with the `@click` handler?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`@click` will not trigger the method `executeLoader` with vue multiselect.  You can use `@input` - which is similar to `v-on:change`, `@close`, `@select` as in example below:

```
<multiselect placeholder="Pick at least one"
  select-label="Enter doesn’t work here!"
  :value="value"
  :options="options"
  :multiple="true"
  :searchable="true"
  :allow-empty="false"
  :hide-selected="true"
  :max-height="150"
  :max="3"
  :disabled="isDisabled"
  :block-keys="['Tab', 'Enter']"
  @input="onChange"
  @close="onTouch"
  @select="onSelect">
</multiselect>
```

In your case I would try `@input="executeLoader"`

Comment: how to send any extra parameter with function "executeLoader"
I tried this @input="executeLoader($event)", but its not working.

Comment: The `@input` event is emitted with only the value and the id of the component. In order to send extra parameters to `@input` you would need to create a child component and `emit` the extra parameters from child component to the parent component.  Here you can see a working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/v06l9z6743 . I hope this can solve your issue

Answer (score 1):

In vue-multiselect, since it is a component you can't treat it to behave like a simple `<select>` element.

In components, when you expect them to behave and "listen" to click events just like other html tag, then you should add an event modifier called:  `.native`.

So, you can do on any component:

```
<... @click.native="executeLoader" />
```

But that is not what you are looking for I think. You want to trigger a function when you add more and more tags, or in short: when the selected items increase.

for that, vue-multiselect exposes the `@input` event, so you can handle using:

```
<... @input="executeLoader" />
```

And now just call `executeLoader` and accept the arguments as:

```
methods: {
  executeLoader(selectedItems) {} 
}
```